# Make text of different length scroll at same speed

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have lines of text that scroll to the left on hover, currently they all scroll at different speeds depending on how much text there is inside the span tags. How can I make them all scroll at the same speed regardless of text length? I imagine this will be possible with some javascript but I am unsure.

```css
.menu {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;

    --marquee-width: 100vw;
    --offset: 20vw;
    --move-initial: calc(-25% + var(--offset));
    --move-final: calc(-50% + var(--offset));
    --item-font-size: 10vw;
    counter-reset: menu;
}

.menu__item {
    cursor: default;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 50px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .menu__item {
        cursor: default;
        position: relative;
        padding: 0 20px;
    }
}


.menu__item-link {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
}

.menu__item-link::before {
    all: initial;
    font-family: sofia-pro, sans-serif;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 60%;
    left: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.menu__item-link:hover {
    transition-duration: 0.1s;
    opacity: 0;
}

.marquee {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: var(--marquee-width);
    overflow: hidden;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.marquee__inner {
    width: fit-content;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    transform: translate3d(var(--move-initial), 0, 0);
    animation: scroll 5s linear infinite;
    animation-play-state: paused;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.1s;
}

.menu__item-link:hover ~ .marquee .marquee__inner {
    animation-play-state: running;
    opacity: 1;
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    z-index: 9999;
}

.menu__item-link, .marquee span {
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-size: 8vw;
    padding: 0 1vw;
    font-weight: 900;
    line-height: 1.15;
}

.marquee span {
    font-style: italic;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 3px #FB4D98;
    text-stroke: 3px #FB4D98;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    text-fill-color: transparent;
    color: transparent;
    transition: opacity 0.1s;
    letter-spacing: 1.5px;
}

@keyframes scroll {
    0% {
        transform: translate3d(var(--move-initial), 0, 0);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translate3d(var(--move-final), 0, 0);
    }
}
```

```html
<nav class="menu">
    <div class="menu__item">
        <a class="menu__item-link" target="_blank">DJ SNAKE</a>
        <div class="marquee">
            <div class="marquee__inner" aria-hidden="true">
                <span>DJ SNAKE</span>
                <span>DJ SNAKE</span>
                <span>DJ SNAKE</span>
                <span>DJ SNAKE</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<nav class="menu">
    <div class="menu__item">
        <a class="menu__item-link" target="_blank">AXWELL INGROSSO</a>
        <div class="marquee">
            <div class="marquee__inner" aria-hidden="true">
                <span>AXWELL INGROSSO</span>
                <span>AXWELL INGROSSO</span>
                <span>AXWELL INGROSSO</span>
                <span>AXWELL INGROSSO</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<nav class="menu">
    <div class="menu__item">
        <a class="menu__item-link" target="_blank">ELIJAH</a>
        <div class="marquee">
            <div class="marquee__inner" aria-hidden="true">
                <span>ELIJAH</span>
                <span>ELIJAH</span>
                <span>ELIJAH</span>
                <span>ELIJAH</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Do you know the maximum length of your text? Or your text will be dynamic?

Comment: it will be dynamic

Comment: you could play around with the `.marquee__inner`'s `width` and set it for example to `500px;`... however, that wouldn't give you the infinite effect... another option is to add some js-goodness and adjust the animation-speed according to the text length... but that's not a pure css solution

Comment: doesnt have to be pure CSS, JS is absolutely fine, Im just unsure about the JS code required.

Answer (score 1):

A solution is to define width to have the same width for all div.

```js
/*(function() {
  var mySpans = document.querySelectorAll(".marquee__inner");
  var elementSpanWidth = 0;

  mySpans.forEach((span) => {
     if(span.offsetWidth > elementSpanWidth)
      elementSpanWidth = span.offsetWidth;
  });
  
  console.log(elementSpanWidth);
  
  mySpans.forEach((span) => {
     span.style.width = elementSpanWidth;
  });
  
  
})();*/
```

```css
.menu {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;

    --marquee-width: 100vw;
    --offset: 20vw;
    --move-initial: calc(-25% + var(--offset));
    --move-final: calc(-50% + var(--offset));
    --item-font-size: 10vw;
    counter-reset: menu;
}

.menu__item {
    cursor: default;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 50px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .menu__item {
    cursor: default;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 20px;
}
}


.menu__item-link {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;

}

.menu__item-link::before {
    all: initial;
    font-family: sofia-pro, sans-serif;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 60%;
    left: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.menu__item-link:hover {
    transition-duration: 0.1s;
    opacity: 0;
}



.marquee {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: var(--marquee-width);
    overflow: hidden;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.marquee__inner {
    width: fit-content;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    transform: translate3d(var(--move-initial), 0, 0);
    animation: scroll 5s linear infinite;
    animation-play-state: paused;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.1s;
}

.menu__item-link:hover ~ .marquee .marquee__inner {
    animation-play-state: running;
    opacity: 1;
    transition-duration: 0.4s;

    z-index: 9999;
}


.menu__item-link,
.marquee span {
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-size: 8vw;
    padding: 0 1vw;
    font-weight: 900;
    line-height: 1.15;

    
}

.marquee span {
    font-style: italic;
        -webkit-text-stroke: 3px #FB4D98;
    text-stroke: 3px #FB4D98;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    text-fill-color: transparent;
    color: transparent;
    transition: opacity 0.1s;
    letter-spacing: 1.5px;

}

@keyframes scroll {
    0% {
        transform: translate3d(var(--move-initial), 0, 0);
    }

    100% {
        transform: translate3d(var(--move-final), 0, 0);
    }
}
```

```html
<nav class="menu">
            <div class="menu__item">
                <a class="menu__item-link" target="_blank">DJ SNAKE
   
  </a>
                <div class="marquee">
                    <div class="marquee__inner" aria-hidden="true">
<span>DJ SNAKE</span>
<span>DJ SNAKE</span>
<span>DJ SNAKE</span>
<span>DJ SNAKE</span>   </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

<nav class="menu">
            <div class="menu__item">
                <a class="menu__item-link" target="_blank">AXWELL INGROSSO
   
  </a>
                <div class="marquee">
                    <div class="marquee__inner" aria-hidden="true">
                        <span>AXWELL INGROSSO</span>
                        <span>AXWELL INGROSSO</span>
                        <span>AXWELL INGROSSO</span>
                        <span>AXWELL INGROSSO</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

<nav class="menu">
            <div class="menu__item">
                <a class="menu__item-link" target="_blank">ELIJAH
   
  </a>
                <div class="marquee">
                    <div class="marquee__inner" aria-hidden="true">
                        <span>ELIJAH</span>
                        <span>ELIJAH</span>
                        <span>ELIJAH</span>
                        <span>ELIJAH</span>
            </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

The second option is to use JavaScript to get the maximum width and fix dynamically on other div.

Comment: the width needs to be 100% so that the text scrolls in and out of the edges of the screen at any browser size. I think JS is the solution but I have no idea what the code would be. Are you able to help out please?

Comment: Are you able to help out?

Comment: Could you try this new one

Comment: Thats almost it! They are all moving at the same speed now, but if you look at each of the bits of text in your example, after a few seconds they jump. This is the problem I was having when trying to get them all to move at the same speed.

Comment: I will try to do it. Honestly, it's not easy.